# Using sub-domains with Google Analytics

Tags: dns, google-analytics, subdomain

I have added Google Analytics to my primary domain and added the script to the head section of each page. I have done similarly with a sub-domain. Both the primary domain and the sub-domain are showing under the primary domain statistics.

I have used the multi-domain script in each head section. I have created a filter by following the Google instructions, but the filtered profile doesn't show anything at all.

How can I get statistics for each domain & sub-domain separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

very simple, just create separate profile for each sub-domain and add profile specific code into all the pages of respective sub-domain.